# loop in score and saving in database

Tags: android, database

I am having a problem in looping/adding the score. What I have here is only a method/equation for adding the score. Can anyone help me loop this? What I mean is that when a button is clicked, the corresponding score in the database should add. Example, I have an apple which is equivalent to 1 and a condense milk which is equivalent to 5, this should automatically sum up to 6(same process as i add more fruits). So this is what I mean in loop in score.

I also have a timer and what I want is that when the time is over, the sum or total should also automatically save into the database.

Can anyone help me about this matter?

**Formula I use for addition**

```
private void calculate(){
    x = Integer.parseInt(tv3.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
    y = Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
    z = x + y;
    score.setText(Integer.toString(z));
}
```

Comment: So you want to add z to the value in database each time the button is clicked ?

Comment: @Dexter the value of x and y value will be added continuously before the time runs out and at the end of the timer the value of which is the sum of x and y will only be the one to be saved in the database.

Comment: then why don’t you simply maintain a global integer z and replace z = x + y with z += (x+y); then when timer runs out store this z into your database

Comment: @Dexter how to store z ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly store the score in a global int z

```
private int z = 0;
private void calculate(){
    x = Integer.parseInt(tv3.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
    y = Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
    z += (x + y);
    score.setText(Integer.toString(z));
}
```

Then once your timer runs out, store this z into shared-preferences like this

```
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Some Name",
Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); (assuming you are in the activity)
        editor.putInt("totalScore", z);
        editor.apply();
```

You can retrieve this value z this way :

```
int z = getSharedPreferences("Some Name",
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("totalScore", 0); //again, assuming you are in the MainActivity
```

In case you are not in the Activity, use

```
context.getSharedPreferences("Some Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Comment: what do you mean "not in the Activity"? Can I post my whole MainActivity and tell me where to put these? This is my first app im sorry im too confused.

Comment: Its ok, see your MainActivity class extends Activity. Because of this getSharedPreferences method is available to it. If you are operating in a class which does not extend Activity you will have to get hold of a Context object "which is not null". From what you just said I think you are good to use getSharedPreferences, directly. :) P.S : do read the relevant android documentation.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html and this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: I'm sorry it takes 12345.. days to respond again I had connection problem. I wanted to ask about the above codes you've provided ---> editor.putInt("totalScore", z);
What is totalScore there? is it the textview?